# How to save an array as an image in PyQt

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt

I am writing an application in PyQt where I display some graphs with matplotlib. To do so, I use the following code :

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg
import matplotlib.figure as fig
self.IntFig = fig.Figure()
self.IntBeamCanvas = FigureCanvasQTAgg(self.IntFig)
self.AxesIntInit = self.IntFig.add_subplot(111)
self.AxesIntInit.hold(False)
self.AxesIntInit.imshow(self.Int,extent =[-xx/2+xx/N,xx/2,-xx/2+xx/N,xx/2])
self.IntBeamCanvas.draw()
```

Later in the code I manage to save the figure created with the following code :

```
fname = QtGui.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self,'Save Intensity','C:' )
self.IntFig.savefig(str(fname))
```

But this saves only the figures (with its axes I mean). What if I want to save only the data

```
self.Int
```

that is displayed? I know the the pyplot.imsave method but don't know how to use it here, since I do not use pyplot but figure.Figure.

Does anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the image by following method:

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl

y, x = np.ogrid[-1:1:50j, -1:1:100j]
z = np.sqrt(x*x + y*y)

im = pl.imshow(z)
img = im.make_image()
h, w, s = img.as_rgba_str()
a = np.fromstring(s, dtype=np.uint8).reshape(h, w, 4)
pl.imsave("tmp.png", a)
```

the saved image:

[image]

Comment: That's not what I had in mind but it works. I used pyplot instead of pylab, as I mentionned in my question... I don't know why I did not tought of it in the first time. Thanks anyway!